# Identifier not found for function defined in a .h file

Tags: c++, identifier

I keep getting the "Identifier not found"-error, when I try to run my program...
I've declared the function in a .h file, implemented it in a .cpp file and I try to use it in my main file.

Can you help?

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>    // using IO functions
#include<fstream>
#include "SokobanSolver.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    loadFile();

    system("pause");
}
```

As seen above, I remembered to include the SokobanSolver.h in the main.cpp file...

```
//SokobanSolver.h
#ifndef SOKOBANSOLVER_H
#define SOKOBANSOLVER_H

#include"Position.h"
#include<vector>
#include <iostream>    // using IO functions

using namespace std;

class SokobanSolver {
private:
    vector<Position> walls;
    vector<Position> goals;
    vector<Position> boxes;


//member functions
public:
    void loadFile();

};

#endif
```

---

```
//SokobanSolver.cpp
#include"SokobanSolver.h"
#include"Position.h"
#include<vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void SokobanSolver::loadFile()
{
    ifstream input("problemFile.txt");
    char ch;

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    while (input.get(ch))
    {
        //new line?
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            row++;
            col = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ch == '#')
                walls.push_back(Position(row, col));
            else if (ch == '.')
                goals.push_back(Position(row, col));
            else if (ch == '$')
                boxes.push_back(Position(row, col));
            col++;
        }
    }
}
```

I also put the SokobanSolver.h in the SokobanSolver.cpp file... So I don't get, why it can't find the function loadFile.

Comment: You need a `SokobanSolver`  object to call loadFile() on. `loadFile()` is a class member of the `SokobanSolver` class not a free function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you need a `SokobanSolver` object to call the member function `loadFile`:

```
int main() {
    
    SokobanSolver solver; 
    solver.loadFile();

    system("pause");
}
```